# Building a timestamp from date, time, and meridian fields

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a legacy system that uses four discrete fields to capture a datetime: one for the date (ex. 10/23/2015), one for the hour (ex, 10), one for the minutes (ex, 45), and one for the meridian (A or P).

I am trying to build a scalar function in MSSQL 2008 R2 that will take all of the fields above as arguments and return a datetime value created with all of the supplied values.

This is what I have thus far:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_getTimeStamp (@date Date, @hour Varchar, @minute Varchar, @meridian Varchar)
    RETURNS Datetime
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @createdDateTime datetime
        DECLARE @createdTime varchar

        SELECT @createdTime = @hour + ':' + @minute +
            CASE
                WHEN @meridian = 'A' Then 'am'
                WHEN @meridian = 'P' Then 'pm'
                Else 'pm'
            END

        SET @createdDateTime = @date + CAST(@createdTime AS DATETIME)

        RETURN @createdDateTime
    END
```

The idea is to take the fields that are needed to create the time and combine them into a string that looks like a time value then add it to the already existing date field.

I'm currently receiving the following error in my query:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I should note that in the query utilizing this function I am only sending in non-null values.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the fields you're passing as parameters the same datatypes as you've declared in your function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came with this solution. I think using such built-in functions as [DATEADD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) solves this quite nice. That's the script I've used:

**DATEADD:**

> Returns a specified date with the specified number interval (signed
> integer) added to a specified datepart of that date.

**DATEPART:**

> Returns an integer that represents the specified datepart of the
> specified date.

**Actual query:**

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '10/23/2015'
  , @hour VARCHAR(20) = 10
  , @minute VARCHAR(20) = 45
  , @meridian VARCHAR(20) = 'P'
  , @time DATETIME;
  
SELECT @time = @hour + ':' + @minute + CASE @meridian
    WHEN 'A' THEN 'AM'
    WHEN 'P' THEN 'PM'
    ELSE 'PM'
  END


SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEPART(MINUTE, @time), DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HOUR, @time), @date));
```

I've built a query on [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/379892). It brings back this result for my scenario:

```
2015-10-23 22:45:00
```

What it does?

1. It creates a time string, which is then converted into datetime
2. Then it extracts minutes and hours(where meridian is already processed) from created string using DATEPART and adds values to given date using DATEADD

**P.S.** Always declare lenghts for your VARCHARs.

> If you don't define a length, SQL Server will assign one for you, and
> it may not be as wide as you expect.  In some scenarios, it will be 1.

<sup>Source: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)</sup>

Comment: @JoshuaBrewster I'm glad I helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

There's only one spot in your code that is attempting to convert a date/time from a string:

`CAST(@createdTime AS DATETIME)`

You have values somewhere that do not result in a string that can be converted.

You can find the offending values using your time building logic along with `ISDATE()` in a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE ISDATE(CAST(Hour AS VARCHAR(10)+':'+CAST(Minute AS VARCHAR(10)) = 0
```

Things like `'2:4am'` will cast as datetime without issue, so your format isn't inherently problematic.

After you fix this you should have another error regarding incompatible data types, because you can't add a `DATE` and a `DATETIME`, so you'll need to change:

```
SET @createdDateTime = @date + CAST(@createdTime AS DATETIME)
```

To:

```
SET @createdDateTime = CAST(@date AS DATETIME) + CAST(@createdTime AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an awful lot of type conversion going on in there. This expression `@date + CAST(@createdTime AS DATETIME)` is most likely the line giving you the error. The output is probably `2012-01-01 00:00:002012-01-01 10:45:00'

A better approach would be to simply add the time onto the original date. Note that I changed the data types in the function to make it that the type conversion isn't happening in the function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_getTimeStamp (@date Date, @hour INT, @minute INT, @meridian CHAR(1))
RETURNS Datetime
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TEMP DATETIME
    SET @TEMP = @date
    IF @hour < 12
        SET @TEMP = DATEADD(HOUR, @date, @hour)
    SET @TEMP = DATEADD(MINUTE, @date, @minute)

    IF @meridian = 'P' AND @hour < 13 -- the hour must already be PM
        SET @TEMP = DATEADD(HOUR, @date, 12)

    RETURN @TEMP
END
```

Note: I have not tested this in SQL Server. I may have a typo or two in there. But, the concept should be sound.

Comment: Thanks. I should note that the hour field is not a 24 hour time format field. That is, 1PM would be 1 in the hour field and P in the meridian field.

Comment: And, this code should accommodate that. I try to be paranoid when I write a function or something that some random person other than me might use (not meaning you, just someone that goes browsing through the functions available in a database and says "hey, I can use that for my unrelated purpose").